# NHIbernate 3 can't automap XmlDocument property

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I'm trying to map a type where one of the properties is an `XmlDocument` but I get this error:

> NHibernate.MappingException : An association from the table ChangeLog_TestAuditHistory refers to an unmapped class: System.Xml.XmlDocument

I am using Fluent NHibernate automappings. NHibernate version 3.0.0.4000 and Fluent NHibernate version 1.2.0.694. I know NHibernate is supposed to support xml columns, but I've never seen any examples using auto mappings.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably a bug in Fluent, or a wrong convention... you probably need to tell it that XmlDocument is not an entity.

If you map it as a regular property, NH will use the correct mapping by default.

Comment: so...how do I "tell it that `XmlDocument` is not an entity"? I'm not doing anything to it right now, it looks just like the other properties

Comment: @kelloti: I don't know... I don't use fluent. But it definitely looks like a bug.